# Drag and Drop в wpf. Те элементs которые я обьявил в xaml перетаскиваются, но когда я в listBox добавляю новые элементы они не перетаскиваются. Help>

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, drag, drop

Тут xaml

```
<Window x:Class="ФормаСписка.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ФормаСписка"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid x:Name="MainGrid">
        <TextBox x:Name="txtSurname" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="32,19,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="txtName" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="32,42,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
        <Button Content="Регистрация" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="38" Margin="32,88,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Click="Button_Click"/>
        <ListBox x:Name="listBox" Margin="18,206,430,10" AllowDrop="True" Drop="listBox_Drop" PreviewMouseMove="listBox_PreviewMouseMove">
            <ListBoxItem Content="123123"></ListBoxItem>  </ListBox>
        <Label Content="Фамилия" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="157,15,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Height="26"/>
        <Label Content="Имя" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="157,37,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="76" Height="27"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="txtLogin" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="32,65,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
        <Label Content="Логин" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="157,60,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="76" Height="27"/>
        <ListBox x:Name="listBoxCommandPreview" Margin="400,321,48,11" AllowDrop="True" Drop="listBoxCommandPreview_Drop" PreviewMouseMove="listBoxCommandPreview_PreviewMouseMove"/>
        <Button Content="Создать команду" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="400,292,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="CreateCommand" Height="23"/>
        <Label x:Name="chek" Content="---" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="400,261,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

xaml.cs

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

        List<UserInfo> users;
        List<Teams> teams;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            users = new List<UserInfo>();
            teams = new List<Teams>();
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            users.Add(new(txtName.Text, txtSurname.Text, txtLogin.Text));  //Добавляет в лист users user'а по конструктору UserInfo, Имя и Фамилия. В конструкторе AllName = Фамилия + Имя//
            txtName.Clear();
            txtSurname.Clear();     
            txtLogin.Clear();
            ListBoxRefresh();
        }

        private void ListBoxRefresh()
        {
            listBox.Items.Clear();
            foreach (UserInfo user in users)
            {
                listBox.Items.Add(user.Login);
            }
        }

        private void CreateCommand(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            listBoxCommandPreview.Items.Clear();
        }

        private void listBox_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop) is ListBoxItem listItem)
            {
                listBox.Items.Add(listItem);
                listBox.Items.Refresh();
            }
        }

        private void listBoxCommandPreview_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop) is ListBoxItem listItem)
            {
                listBoxCommandPreview.Items.Add(listItem);
                listBoxCommandPreview.Items.Refresh();
            }
        }

        private void listBox_PreviewMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            Point mPos = e.GetPosition(null);

            if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed &&
                Math.Abs(mPos.X) > SystemParameters.MinimumHorizontalDragDistance &&
                Math.Abs(mPos.Y) > SystemParameters.MinimumVerticalDragDistance)
            {
                try
                {
                    ListBoxItem selectedItem = (ListBoxItem)listBox.SelectedItem;
                    listBox.Items.Remove(selectedItem);
                    DragDrop.DoDragDrop(this, new DataObject(DataFormats.FileDrop, selectedItem), DragDropEffects.Copy);

                    if (selectedItem.Parent == null)
                    {
                        listBox.Items.Add(selectedItem);
                    }
                }
                catch { }

            }
        }

        private void listBoxCommandPreview_PreviewMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            Point mPos = e.GetPosition(null);

            if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed &&
                Math.Abs(mPos.X) > SystemParameters.MinimumHorizontalDragDistance &&
                Math.Abs(mPos.Y) > SystemParameters.MinimumVerticalDragDistance)
            {
                try
                {
                    ListBoxItem selectedItem = (ListBoxItem)listBoxCommandPreview.SelectedItem;
                    listBoxCommandPreview.Items.Remove(selectedItem);
                    DragDrop.DoDragDrop(this, new DataObject(DataFormats.FileDrop, selectedItem), DragDropEffects.Copy);

                    if (selectedItem.Parent == null)
                    {
                        listBoxCommandPreview.Items.Add(selectedItem);
                    }
                }
                catch { }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Мне кажется проблема в try catch, когда я делаю проверку на то что выбранный элемент является выбранным элементом типа (ListBoxItem). Но это лишь предположение, так я не пойму почему не работает.

Comment: Ваша проблема в том, что вы неправильно используете WPF изначально. WPF это в первую очередь XAML и привязки, если вы их игнорируете, вы лишаетесь уймы всего полезного, и делаете уйму всего сами. Простой пример, текст в текстовое поле, как? `textBox1.Text = "Текст";`, верно? Нет, ибо вы дергаете UI, храните в нем данные напрямую, правильно будет `this.DataContext = this;`, далее `public string Text {get;set;} = "Текст";`, ну и в XAML `<TextBox Text = "{Binding Text}"/>`, все. Заметьте, нету даже `x:Name`. Вот так у вас и должен строится весь проект. Используете в C# UI = делаете что-то не так.

Comment: Также всякие `Margin="400,321,48,11"` - это сразу означает то, что вы используете дизайнер студии для размещения элементов, ну а он вам позиционирует все криво. Чуть поменяете размеры окна, все, у вас все съедет, будут другие граф. артефакты. Научитесь писать код руками! У вас должна быть сетка (`Grid`) или панель (например `StackPanel`), в ней уже элементы, которые сами подстроятся под все.